Flutter is there a way to get the project file where the error occured at?
When debugging and a error occurs I can see in the debug console in what file which file caused it, but I can't find the file path anywhere in the FlutterErrorDetails (details) object returned from:
  FlutterError.onError = (details) async {
    inspect(details);
  };

If it isn't there, is there another way of getting it?
I tried looking for it details.stack and details.context but no success.

see stack
